# How to do an unbuffered file transfer using API ReadFile() WriteFile()?

Tags: delphi, winapi

The problem is that when I disable the cache (setting `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` in `CreateFile`) I must pass to the read and write function a number of bytes that is a multiple of 512 (sector size). I use a buffer of 10MB and everything it's ok... until the last buffer operation. The last buffer does not have a multiple of 512 number of bytes. So, how do I read and write this final portion of the file ?

This is what I wrote so far...

```
procedure MarusCopyFileNoCache(SrcName,DestName:string);
const BufSize = 10485760; {10MB}
var Src,Dest:THandle;
    Buffer:Pointer;
    Bufs,x:integer;
    AllSize:int64;
    N,junk:DWord;
begin
 Src:=CreateFileW(PWideChar('\\?\'+SrcName), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 0);
 Dest:=CreateFileW(PWideChar('\\?\'+DestName), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 0);
 try
   AllSize:=MFileSize(Src); {this is my function to get the int64 file size} 
   Bufs:=Ceil(AllSize/BufSize);
   GetMem(Buffer,BufSize);
   try
    for x:=1 to Bufs do begin
     ReadFile(Src, Buffer^, BufSize, N, nil);
     WriteFile(Dest, Buffer^, N, junk, nil);
    end;
   finally
    FreeMem(Buffer,BufSize);
   end;
 finally
  CloseHandle(Src);
  CloseHandle(Dest);
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `GetMem` would return a buffer with sector size alignment? I don't think so, although I don't know. See docs for `ReadFile` and [`FileBuffering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc644950%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't think so either, but I've tested it and it seems it's working even with `GetMem`. I don't know why. It's strange. Anyway I will use `VirtualAlloc` in the final version just to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, you have to read and write full sectors, but the last buffer will be a partial sector (`ReadFile()` will report fewer bytes read than the full sector size) .  When you write that last buffer, you still have to write it as a full sector or else `WriteFile()` will fail.  So obviously the output file size may be too large.  However, since you do know the desired file size, you can use [`SetFileInformationByHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539.aspx) to set the output file's final size after you are done writing to it and before you close its handle.

For example:

```
type
  FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS = (
    FileBasicInfo                   = 0,
    FileStandardInfo                = 1,
    FileNameInfo                    = 2,
    FileRenameInfo                  = 3,
    FileDispositionInfo             = 4,
    FileAllocationInfo              = 5,
    FileEndOfFileInfo               = 6,
    FileStreamInfo                  = 7,
    FileCompressionInfo             = 8,
    FileAttributeTagInfo            = 9,
    FileIdBothDirectoryInfo         = 10, // 0xA
    FileIdBothDirectoryRestartInfo  = 11, // 0xB
    FileIoPriorityHintInfo          = 12, // 0xC
    FileRemoteProtocolInfo          = 13, // 0xD
    FileFullDirectoryInfo           = 14, // 0xE
    FileFullDirectoryRestartInfo    = 15, // 0xF
    FileStorageInfo                 = 16, // 0x10
    FileAlignmentInfo               = 17, // 0x11
    FileIdInfo                      = 18, // 0x12
    FileIdExtdDirectoryInfo         = 19, // 0x13
    FileIdExtdDirectoryRestartInfo  = 20, // 0x14
    MaximumFileInfoByHandlesClass);

  FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFO = record
    EndOfFile: LARGE_INTEGER;
  end;

function SetFileInformationByHandle(
  hFile: THandle;
  FileInformationClass: FILE_INFO_BY_HANDLE_CLASS;
  lpFileInformation: Pointer;
  dwBufferSize: DWORD
  ): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll' delayed;
```

```
procedure MarcusCopyFileNoCache(SrcName, DestName: string);
const
  BufSize = 10485760; {10MB}
var
  Src, Dest: THandle;
  Buffer: PByte;
  FinalSize: Int64;
  SectorSize, N, ignored: DWORD;
  eof: FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFO;
begin
  Src := CreateFile(PChar('\\?\'+SrcName), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 0);
  if Src = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    Dest := CreateFile(PChar('\\?\'+DestName), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 0);
    if Dest = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      try
        FinalSize := 0;
        SectorSize := 512; // <-- TODO: determine this dynamically at runtime
        GetMem(Buffer, BufSize);
        try
          repeat
            if not ReadFile(Src, Buffer^, BufSize, N, nil) then RaiseLastOSError;
            if N = 0 then Break; // EOF reached
            Inc(FinalSize, N);
            // round up the number of bytes read to the next sector boundary for writing
            N := (N + (SectorSize-1)) and (not (SectorSize-1));
            if not WriteFile(Dest, Buffer^, N, ignored, nil) then RaiseLastOSError;
          until False;
        finally
          FreeMem(Buffer, BufSize);
        end;
        // now set the final file size
        eof.EndOfFile.QuadPart := FinalSize;
        if not SetFileInformationByHandle(Dest, FileEndOfFileInfo, @eof, SizeOf(eof)) then RaiseLastOSError;
      finally
        CloseHandle(Dest);
      end;
    except
      DeleteFile(PChar(DestName));
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(Src);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The reading it's ok, but if I write only whole buffers I can't control the file size...

Comment: Yes, you can. If `WriteFile()` won't let you write a partial sector buffer at the end of the file, you can always use `SetEndOfFile()` to set the EOF marker at the desired file offset.

Comment: No. That doesn't work with an unbuffered file. Which is what I cover in my answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Are you sure about that? `SetFileInformationByHandle` is Vista only but XP (and earlier) supported unbuffered files just fine.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: I think David was referring to the fact that `SetEndOfFile()` marks EOF at the current file offset but you cannot seek an unbuffered file to an offset that is not an even multiple of the media's sector size. `SetFileInformationByHandle()` solves that problem. And FYI, `SetFileInformationByHandle()` is available in XP via `FileExtd.lib` (which is not usable in Delphi unless you wrap it in a C/C++ DLL).

Answer (score 4):

I think you know the answer. You need to read, or write, a multiple of the sector size. That's a given.

When reading, I guess this means that for the final read, the read will succeed, but you won't read the entire buffer. That will be apparent from `lpNumberOfBytesRead`. Fine. It's no problem to ask to read a full buffer, but only have as many bytes read as are left in the file.

So you don't need to check the size of the file, you can just keep reading until the read doesn't return any more bytes. And while we are on this topic, don't use floating point arithmetic here. Use `div` and `mod`, integer operators.

For writing, you need to write the final block of data, rounded up to a multiple of sector size. This will write too much, potentially. You can't fix this by calling `SetEndOfFile` with your unbuffered handle. Instead call `SetFileInformationByHandle`. Pass `FileEndOfFileInfo` and specify the true length of the file.

Comment: `SetEndOfFile` set the file size to the current position of the file pointer. But, in a file opened with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` the `SetFilePointer` works only with values that are multiple of the sector size.

Comment: I know. Hence what I wrote in my answer. Please read it again more closely.

Comment: I do not know if this will work with a handle that has `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, but another option might be to use [`SetFileInformationByHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539.aspx) with the `FileInformationClass` parameter set to `FileEndOfFileInfo` and the `lpFileInformation` parameter set to a pointer to a [`FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364224.aspx) struct that specifies the desired EOF offset.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's the solution. I just tested it and it works like a charm.